# What is the next number in the sequence?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

What is the next number in the following sequence?

> 9999999, 4782969, 217728, 1568, ???

I saw this question in an app and I am stuck. Can you help me?
Source: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.broli.whatsnext

Answer (score 16):

The next number is

> 240

And the following is

> 0

Because:

> Each number is the product of the digits of the preceding number: `9*9*9*9*9*9*9=4782969`, `4*7*8*2*9*6*9=217728`, `2*1*7*7*2*8=1568`, and so the next number in the sequence is `1*5*6*8=240`, and finally `2*4*0=0`, where the sequence ends.

Comment: One way to look at it is that the sequence ends.  Another way is that it goes on forever, in an incredibly boring manner.

Comment: @MooingDuck Without letting any spoilers slip, Martin Gardiner once expostulated on some interesting properties of such sequences, in particular of their *lengths*, which of course requires us to define the sequences to be finite.

Comment: It will be interesting if the distribution of getting to a certain value from a starting number will be different than 10%

Comment: I feel like the final result for any starting value is either an endless string of 0's, or more rarely an endless string of 1's.  I'm curious if there are starting values that can end in any other way, either cycling on the same number, or in a repeating chain of some sort.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think it could end as an endless string of any single digit, 0 being the most likely. If you only use positive integers I can't think of how it would cycle because I can't think of how it could ever increase.